# Nested object Elastic search based on max value

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a simple class

```
public class Foo 
{
   public List<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
   public DateTime Timestamp {get;set;}
}
```

This is saved in Elastic. I'm using Nest client to search for a `Foo`. What I need to do is return `Foo`s but only return the latest `Bar` based on `Timestamp`.

I'm using `Aggregations` but this just gives me the Max Timestamp, which I need but then I need to make another call to Elastic to get it? It seems like that is not right. Is there a way that I can search for a `Foo` document but the nested object `Bar`, I only want to return the one with the max timestamp i.e the List should just have one `Bar` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with DisMax function like

```
var res = await _client.SearchAsync<Foo>(s => s
                                    .Query(q => q
                                        .Bool(b => b
                                            .Must(
                                                mu => mu.DisMax(d => d.Name("Bars"))))));
```

Comment: How does it know to use `Timestamp` as the property to compare?